# How to develop a simple prog, to sendkeys to another program?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to develop a simple program which will show a form with a listbox and a button. The buttom will allow a listbox entry to be selected and close the form. The entry will them be sent to the previous open application.

For example, I could select my postcode from the listbox and have it sent to the currently selected field in my internet browser. Or the current date to my text editor.

This is what I have, which doesn't work, it seems to bring up my task bar.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Form1.ShowDialog()
        SendKeys.SendWait("fred") 'I'll substitute fred later.
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub
End Module
```

I intend to create a shortcut and a ssign a hot key to start the program, i'm justing running it from the ide at the moment.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You would need the window handle to send the keys to. As long as your app has "focus" any sendkeys you send would go to your app anyways. What you may want to consider is using the clipboard to store the data from your winform and then simply paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this tool AutoIt - http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/